# How to fix 'ImportError: cannot import name 'ttk'' in Python 3.6.8

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, python-3.6, ttk

I am trying to create a GUI for a Python program I wrote. For that I'd like to import ttk from the tkinter module, which (as far as I know) shouldn't require further installations in Python 3.6.8. I have been programming for 3 months now, so please excuse if the answer is trivial for you, I am still new to Python (or programming in general ^^).

I have already tried following versions to import ttk:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk 

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.tkk import ttk 

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

The last two gave me the error 
'No module named 'tkinter.ttk'; 'tkinter' is not a package'

```
from tkinter import *
import ttk
```

So how do I import ttk in Python 3.6.8 without running an error?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: The first one you tried is the right solution. My guess is, you've named your program 'tkinter.py' - is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use tkinter unless it is installed on your machine with Python 3.6.8. To check if tkinter is installed, go to the terminal (Command Prompt for Windows) and type the following command:

> python -m tkinter

If this command opens a window displaying a simple Tk interface, that means it's installed correctly and you should be able to import the tkinter package in your program.

However, if it shows an error, I recommend reinstalling Python and make sure that you select TCL/TK and IDLE when it asks you for optional installations.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: It did open the window, but still runs the import error.

Comment: @Jani you will get import error if you try importing it using the "last two" syntax in your original question. It is because of incorrect syntax. Please let me know the specifics about what syntax you are using for the import.

Comment: I fixed it by reinstalling and deleting the pycache. Then the first one worked for importing

Comment: That's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and this worked for me:

"brew install python-tk@3.10"